# File upload error in angularjs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

**service.js:**

```
MyEmployee.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })
        .success(function () {
        })
        .error(function () {
        });
    }
}]);
```

**controller.js:**

```
 MyEmployee.controller('EmployeeDetailController', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload) {

            $scope.uploadFile = function () {
                var file = $scope.myFile;
                console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
                var uploadUrl = "~/Content/Photos";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };

        }]);
```

**directive.js:**

```
MyEmployee.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

**index:**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<section ng-controller="EmployeeDetailController" >

    <alert type="success" close="closeAlert()" collapse="ShowAlert" data-dismiss="alert">
             Employee has been Added Successfully!
    </alert>

    <div style ="float:right;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="EditEmployeeShow = !EditEmployeeShow">Add New Employee</button>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;" collapse="EditEmployeeShow" >
        @Html.Partial("_CreateNewEmployee")
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;" data-ng-init="init()">
        @Html.Partial("_EmpdetList")
    </div> 

</section>
```

**Module:0**

```
angular.module('MyEmployee', ['MyEmployee.controllers',  'MyEmployee.services', 'MyEmployee.directive', 'ngDialog']);
```

**CreateNewEmployee:**

```
<h2>CreateNewEmployee</h2>

<table class="table" style="width: 100%">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 20%;">
           <label class="labelsytle">
             First Name
        </label>           
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" name="search" ng-model="Empdet.FirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" style="border-radius: 5px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <label class="labelsytle">
            Last Name
        </label>            
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" name="search" ng-model="Empdet.LastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" style="border-radius: 5px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <label class="labelsytle">
            Email
        </label>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" name="search" ng-model="Empdet.Email" placeholder="Enter Email" style="border-radius: 5px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <label class="labelsytle">
            PhotoFile
        </label>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" file-model="PhotoFile"  style="border-radius: 5px;"/>  
        <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
           <label class="labelsytle">
            PhotoText
        </label>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" name="search" ng-model="Empdet.PhotoText" placeholder="Enter PhotoText" style="border-radius: 5px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
           <label class="labelsytle">
            Age
        </label>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" name="search" ng-model="Empdet.Age" placeholder="Enter Age" style="border-radius: 5px;" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: block; text-align: center; width: 5%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 25px;" colspan="4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="SaveEmpdet(Empdet)" style="border-radius: 5px; font-family: Consolas;">SAVE</button></td>

    <td style="text-align: left; width: 25px;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="Cancel()" style="border-radius: 5px; font-family: Consolas;">CANCEL</button></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

I'm unable to upload my file when i try to execute my application i am unable to execute the selectemployee list i getting hanged up like this posting an 
Error: "ailed to instantiate module MyEmployee.directive due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyEmployee.directive' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$injector/nomod?p0=MyEmployee.directive"

[image: screenshot of my error application]

Comment: Can you add code with module definitions? (content of MyEmployee,...)

Comment: i have added all the codes.. please help me to find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You define module *MyEmployee* with dependencies on MyEmployee.controllers and MyEmployee.directives modules, but modules MyEmployee.controllers and MyEmployee.directives are not defined in your code snipets.

if variable MyEmployee is defined as

```
var MyEmployee = angular.module('MyEmployee', ['MyEmployee.controllers',  'MyEmployee.services', 'MyEmployee.directive', 'ngDialog']);
```

then `MyEmployee.directive('fileModel',...` is only directive definition in module MyEmployee - MyEmployee.directive is not defined (which tell you angular error message).

If you want define module for every file, use something like this for directives.js (and similarly for each file / module).

```
angular.module('MyEmployee.directive', [])
  .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);
```